# Is this generalization of the Brier score strictly proper?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, convex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a set, and let $\mathcal P$ be the set of finitely additive probability measures defined on $2^\Omega$.

If $\Omega$ is finite with $|\Omega| = N$, then the *Brier score*, defined by
$$B(P, \omega) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{A \subseteq 2^\Omega} (P(A) - 1_A(\omega))^2,\tag{1}$$
for all $P \in \mathcal P$ and $\omega \in \Omega$, is *strictly proper*, that is:
$$\sum_\omega B(P, \omega) P(\omega) \leq \sum_\omega B(Q,\omega)P(\omega)\tag{2}$$
for all $Q \in \mathcal P$, and the inequality is strict unless $Q = P$. The proof involves nothing more than basic calculus.

> I'm wondering if this result can be generalized to arbitrary $\Omega$.

Here's the idea. First, we replace the summation in (1) with some bounded linear functional. In particular, Let $X$ be the linear space of real-valued bounded functions on $2^\Omega$, and let $f_{P, \omega}$ be the function in $X$ defined by $f_{P, \omega}(A) = (P(A) - 1_A(\omega))^2$. Let $\ell$ be a positive bounded linear functional on $X$. Now generalize the definition in (1) by defining
$$B(P, \omega) = \ell(f_{P, \omega}).\tag{3}$$

Next, we replace the sums in (2) with integrals. Since $B(Q, \cdot)$ is non-negative for all $Q \in \mathcal P$, we can define its integral with respect to $P$ as the supremum of the $P$-integrals of simple functions that are dominated by $B(Q,\cdot)$, where the finitely additive integral of a simple function is defined in the usual way. (See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79663/does-integrating-with-respect-to-a-finitely-additive-measure-respect-addition?noredirect=1&lq=1), for example.)

My question, then, is

> Is it true that, with $B$ defined by (3),
> $$\int B(P, \omega)P(d\omega) \leq \int B(Q, \omega)P(d\omega)$$
> holds for all $P,Q \in \mathcal P$, with strict inequality unless $Q = P$?

One idea I had for approaching the problem is to fix $P \in \mathcal P$ and consider the function $g_P: Q \mapsto \int B(Q,\omega)P(d\omega)$. I want to know whether $g_P$ achieves a minimum uniquely at $P$.

Now, by Jensen's inequality $f_{\lambda P_1 + (1-\lambda) P_2, \omega} \leq \lambda f_{P_1, \omega} + (1-\lambda) f_{P_2, \omega}$ holds for all $P_1,P_2 \in P$, $\omega \in \Omega$, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Thus, because $\ell$ and the $P$-integral are both order-preserving, $g_P$ is a convex function. So my question is essentially a convex optimization problem. I'm uncertain how to proceed from here.

Comment: I am not sure how to best generalize the idea, but maybe using (proper) measures instead of finitely additive measures would be preferable? Maybe you could also try to consider a more concrete example for an infinite $\Omega$ first...

Comment: @supinf For a concrete example with $\Omega = \mathbb N$, replace the sum in (1) with the sum over singleton sets, and then $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}(P\{i\} - 1_{\{i\}}(j))$$ should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not true.

For a counterexample, set $\Omega=\Bbb N$
and $\ell(g):=g(\emptyset)$.
Then $\ell$ is a bounded positive linear functional
on $X=2^\Omega$, but $B(Q,\omega)=0$ holds for all $Q,\omega$.
Thus the desired strict inequality can never be satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect that. Any other ideas about how to generalize (2) then?

Comment: What troubles me is that the $\ell$ in your counterexample corresponds to replacing the sum over all $A \subset 2^\Omega$ in (1) with just $P(\emptyset) - 1_{\emptyset}(\omega)$. So I think my proposed generalization is too general. I should require $\ell$ to satisfy additional properties that rule out your counterexample. I'm not sure how to describe the kind of $\ell$ that might work, however.

Comment: Finding a suitable functional $\ell$ can be tricky, not sure if it is even possible.